# how do I get value from BroadcastReceiver activity to main activity

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, installation, referrer

I want get the install referrer value in my `MainActivity`. For that i am using two class

1) `MainActivity`

2) `ReferrerReceiver`

I got received install referrer value successfully in `ReferrerReceiver` class, i tested this using Toast control.

But i can not able to pass this value to `MainActivity` from `ReferrerReceiver`.

Bellow is i tried code. please any one help me.

Thanks for advance.

---

**1) MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        Intent in1= getIntent();
        String ldString = in1.getStringExtra("number");
        tv1.setText(ldString);

    }
}
```

---

**2) ReferrerReceiver.java**

```
public class ReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {           
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (!intent.getAction().equals("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")) {
            return;
        }

          Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
          String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("referrer");
          Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);
          context.startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

---

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myreferrer.in"
      android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.0.6" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"                
         >

        <receiver android:name="com.myreferrer.in.ReferrerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">               
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This was i implemented in my project. its working for me.** **Use this code**

**(1) MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    }

    public static void log(Context context, String string) {
        if(string!=null) {
            Toast.makeText(conte, "Referrer value is."+string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       tv1.setText(string);
    }

}
```

**(2) ReferrerReceiver.java**

```
public class ReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String referrer,rawReferrer;
    public static String getReferrer(Context context) {
        // Return any persisted referrer value or null if we don't have a referrer.
        return context.getSharedPreferences("referrer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("referrer", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
        // Make sure this is the intent we expect - it always should be.
        if ((null != intent) && (intent.getAction().equals("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"))) {
            // This intent should have a referrer string attached to it.
            rawReferrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
            if (null != rawReferrer) {
                // The string is usually URL Encoded, so we need to decode it.
                referrer = URLDecoder.decode(rawReferrer, "UTF-8");                           
                Toast.makeText(context, "ReferrerReceiver." + referrer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MainActivity.log(context,"\nRaw referrer: " + rawReferrer +"\nReferrer: " + referrer);
                MainActivity.log(context,referrer);

                // Persist the referrer string.
                    context.getSharedPreferences("referrer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).
                    edit().putString("referrer", referrer).commit();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ReferrerReceiver." + referrer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MainActivity.log(context,referrer);
                    context.getSharedPreferences("referrer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).
                    edit().putString("referrer", referrer).commit();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ReferrerReceiver intent value is null.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MainActivity.log(context,referrer);
                MainActivity.log(context,"intent value is nulll");
                context.getSharedPreferences("referrer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).
                edit().putString("referrer", "intent value is nulll").commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "ReferrerReceiver catch"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MainActivity.log(context, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**(3) AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myreferrer.in"
      android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.0.6" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"                
         >

        <receiver android:name="com.myreferrer.ReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**(4) sample link:**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your_package_name&referrer=Welcome

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
Intent in1 = new Intent();
String ldString = in1.getStringExtra("KEY");
```

you are declaring new intent which is wrong, and also key you put is also wrong, which should be `number`
Replace it With,

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
String ldString = intent.getStringExtra("number");
```

Comment: i tried this. this too not working.  Intent intent= getIntent();
String ldString = intent.getStringExtra("number");

Comment: install referrer only working in playstore app only na, so i am upload in play store and after publish this app i have install and launch app from play store.   MainActivity class intent received value is 'null'

Answer (score 0):

you have declared your activity as"single Task" in Manifest;so if an instance of your

activity is already launched the system will create (NewIntent) to re_lunch your

activity.try to put this code before onCreate():

@Override

```
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

     super.onNewIntent(intent);

     // NOW getIntent() should always return the recent

     setIntent(intent);
 }
```

to get all the time the newest intent with the new extras.